# How Do I Export Data From HTML Webpage Using Javascript To Microsoft Excel Keeping The GridLines Turned On?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been researching all afternoon and playing around with various solutions I have found on the internet and Stack OverFlow to try to keep the gridlines turned on when I export data from my HTML webpage but to no avail.  I am really trying to avoid using a plug in and something this simple shouldn't require on in my opinion.  I'm actually shocked that this is proving as challenging as it is.  Anyway...I found this code....

```
 function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){

  var downloadLink;
  var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
  var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

  // Specify file name
  filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

  // Create download link element
  downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
      var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
          type: dataType
      });
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
  }else{
      // Create a link to the file
      downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

      // Setting the file name
      downloadLink.download = filename;

      //triggering the function
      downloadLink.click();
      }
  }
```

And coupled with this HTML.....

```
<table id="tblData" class="table10">
    <tr>
      <th class="title36">Description</th>
    </tr>
</table> 

<button onclick="exportTableToExcel('tblData')"</button>
```

It all works beautifully!  Except when I open the file the gridlines are gone and the user would have to go the view tab and turn the gridlines back on every time.  Is there a setting I can change somewhere that will allow this?

The second example in this SO works...but I have a problem whereby I need to use a button and not an input button....for styling purposes...and then in doing so because the solution is written as a var and not a function....I had trouble working it out.  So I know what I'm trying to do is possible...I just can't quite figure out how to work out doing this as Javascript without a plugin.  I'm fairly new at Javascript so thanks in advance for any pointers...perhaps how I can rewrite the second solution as a function?

This is the code that I found that works....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>
```

But I need to rewrite it so that I can call it in like the first function that is referenced at the beginning of my code above.  Thanks again for any pointers or thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I realized the second piece of code was the answer.  I simply needed to update my HTML button reference as follows...

```
<button type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('tblData',)" class="class"><div class="class1"><h3 class="class2">Export To Excel</h3></div></button>
```